# RubyMine tries to run tests from ActionController::TestCase and similar classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rubymine

I'm using `Minitest::Spec` to write my tests. I've added gem 'minitest-reporters' to my Gemfile so that RubyMine can work property. An it is, except some (IMHO) strange behavior.

Let's say I want to run 'uuid_validator_test.rb' file that contains `UUIDValidator` test. I do that right-clicking on the file and then click 'Run ...'. RubyMine starts running the test, but for some strange reason also tries to run tests from `ActionController::TestCase` and similar classes. You can see it on the picture below:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I force it to run just `UUIDValidator` test?